# How does dependency Injection know what variables to pass?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, dependencies, containers

I am struggling with the idea of a dependency injection container.

Not sure how to explain but I will try with a few examples:

```
class foo
{
    public function __construct(\Somenamespace\Bar $bar, $x)
    {

    }
}
```

How would the DIC know what 'x' would be?

And if we go further down the road and look at the bar class. The DIC can with no problem with reflection create Bar.

```
namespace \Somenamespace;
class bar
{
    public function __construct(\SomethingElse\Tap $tap, $y)
    {

    }   
}
```

The bar wants taps and the tap could also be found by the DIC but how does it know about 'y'?

And if we create the tap.

```
namespace\SomethingElse;
class tap
{
    public function __construct($amountOfTaps)
    {

    }
}
```

How would the DIC know about the amount of taps or whatever variable?

**EDIT:**

Same question does for if the hinted type is an interface or an abstract class. How does a DIC figure out what he needs to create?

Comment: It depends on how the DIC is implemented. Are you using Symfony?

Comment: It would be specified in the config for the DIC

Comment: @ChrisHanson Not any DIC specific. Just wondering how it is done. Especially when namespaces come into play. Cause how are they looked up?

Comment: Example implementation: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good and a valid question.

Here is *one of the possible answers*: **the container can't know**

```
public function __construct(\Somenamespace\Bar $bar, $x)
```

- `$bar` is an instance of `\Somenamespace\Bar`, easy
- `$x` could be anything... The container can't know for sure what you want.

So most containers stop here and ask you to explicitly define (e.g. in a configuration file) what dependency should be injected for `$x`.

---

**However** some containers can try to guess. For example:

```
public function __construct($exportService)
```

The container can assume that the variable name can be the service name, so it will try to inject the dependency named `exportService`.

I don't know any PHP container doing that, I'm planning to implement that in the future in [PHP-DI](http://mnapoli.github.io/PHP-DI/).

---

The same goes for **"interface injection"**:

```
public function __construct(Some\GoodInterface $x)
```

In Java, the Container can know all classes that are in a project (they are all grouped in a WAR/JAR archive). So the Java container can look for all implementation of the interface.

If there is only one, it automatically uses it.

In PHP, with autoloading, the container can't know all the classes of your project. So all in all, it can't guess what implementation to inject.

So like above, you will have to define which implementation to use manually (configuration file, …)

Answer (score 0):

My best bet is that IoC containers in PHP use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) (just as IoC containers in .NET and Java do). Here is an example that shows how to reflect over a type and get the parameter names of the parameters of its constructor:

```php
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('SomeClass'); 

$parameters = $reflector->getConstructor()->getParameters();

foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
    echo $parameter->name;
}
```

Comment: How would they know what variable to pass? Lets say I reflect something like \Name\Space\Foo\Bar How do they lookup the variables needed for that specific class?

Comment: I'm a .NET guy, so I might br mistaken, but I believe the convention with PHP DI frameworks is to use the parameter names. There is no type info, this is the only thing they can use. So registration means a dictionary lookup by name.